# Dynamic Page Title Thymeleaf Spring MVC

Tags: spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I'm using Thymeleaf for layouts in my project, but unable to get the page title dynamic.

**Layout.jsp**

```
<head th:fragment="headerfragment">
  <title th:text="@{page-title}"></title>
  <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
  <link th:href="@{/resources/css/bootstrap.min.css}" rel="stylesheet"
    type="text/css" />
</head>
```

**Page.jsp**

```
<head th:include="layout :: headerfragment"></head>
```

When the final page is rendered i see title as ***page-title*** not the actual text

In my controller I set the page-title attribute

```
modelMap.addAttribute("page-title", "Home");
```

I might not be doing it right as i'm new to thymeleaf. Please help me to find out the solution.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The correct syntax is `${page-title}` so in your example it should be changed to `<title th:text="${page-title}"></title>`

Comment: Yes that was the issue... worked like a charm!!! how did i miss such a simple one :(

Comment: If only I had a penny for every time I have said the same thing.  I wouldn't be working. Glad I could help.

Comment: You can make it an expression if you need a static (or dynamic) site title appended: `<title th:text="@{${page-title} + ' - My Awesome Site'}">My Awesome Site</title>`